# Cannot find User Profile Service Application, But still users from AD are reflecting in SharePoint site but not user related properties

Tags: sharepoint, synchronization, profile

I have SharePoint Server 2013 installed. I cannot find any User Profile service application in Service applications list and can see "User Profile service" and "User Profile synchronization services" are STOPPED.

I created new user in AD and added some properties like designation, mobile no. etc., The user is reflecting in SharePoint but no other properties (like mobile no, designation )are reflecting in SharePoint.

When I tried to start user profile sync service it prompts me to select the user profile service application and which is NOT created Yet.

Any help in this situation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create first the UserProfile Synchronization Service. This service is responsible for synching user profile information between AD and SharePoint UserProfile Store. Please see link below for setting up SharePoint UserProfile Synchronization Service:

[Setting up User Profile Synchronization in SharePoint 2013](http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2012/07/23/setting-user-profile-synchronization-service-in-sharepoint-2013/)